# How to get Wikipedia "clean" content?

Tags: php, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I'm using `Mediawiki api` in order to get content from Wikipedia pages.
I've written a code which generates the next query (for example):

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvsection=0&titles=hawaii

Which retrieves only the leading paragraph from the Wikipdia page about Hawaii.

The problem is that as you might notice there are a lot of irrelevant substrings such as:

`"[[Molokai|Moloka{{okina}}i]], [[Lanai|Lāna{{okina}}i]], [[Kahoolawe|Kaho{{okina}}olawe]], [[Maui]] and the [[Hawaii (island)|"`.

All those barckets [[]] are not relevant , and I wonder whether there is an alegant method to pull only 'clean' content from such pages?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you actually want just the first section, or was that just an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a clean HTML text from Wikipedia with this query:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=hawaii

If you want just a plain text, without HTML, try this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&titles=hawaii&explaintext

Answer (score 0):

<s>please try this:</s>

<s>$relevant = preg_replace('/[[.*?]]/', '', $string);</s>

EDIT: just found [this](https://github.com/yohasebe/wp2txt#readme) - hope it is helpful

Comment: This also removes the actual link labels.

Comment: Thanks, it's actually answers my needs -but- I've built a web application so I'll search for a web-like similar feature.